# HRegionServer starts error

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I install `Standalone HBase over HDFS` ,hbase version:2.0.0 Hadoop version: 2.8.4, zookeeper version: 3.4.12 and get error message: `ERROR [regionserver/bynear170:16020] regionserver.HReonServer: pache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary; @98: invokestatic` Reason:
    `Type 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary$Builder' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/QuotaUsage$Builder'`, I don't know what it mean. These are parts of log, how could I fixed it:

```
2018-08-10 13:38:31,365 ERROR [regionserver/bynear170:16020] regionserver.HRegionServer: pache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary; @98: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary$Builder' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/QuotaUsage$Builder'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @98
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/proto/HdfsProtos$ContentSummaryProto', 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary$Builder' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/proto/HdfsProtos$StorageTypeQuotaInfosProto', 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary$Builder' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ac7 0005 01b0 bb03 4159 b703 424c 2b2a
    0x0000010: b603 43b6 0344 2ab6 0345 b603 462a b603
    0x0000020: 47b6 0348 2ab6 0349 b603 4a2a b603 4bb6
    0x0000030: 034c 2ab6 034d b603 4e2a b603 4fb6 0350
    0x0000040: 2ab6 0351 b603 522a b603 53b6 0354 2ab6
    0x0000050: 0355 b603 5657 2ab6 0357 9900 0b2a b603
    0x0000060: 582b b803 592b b603 5ab0               
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@6)
    append_frame(@101,Object[#2149])
 java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocolPB/PBHelperClient.convert(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/proto/HdfsProtos$ContentSummaryProto;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary; @98: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary$Builder' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/QuotaUsage$Builder'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @98
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/proto/HdfsProtos$ContentSummaryProto', 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary$Builder' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/proto/HdfsProtos$StorageTypeQuotaInfosProto', 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary$Builder' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ac7 0005 01b0 bb03 4159 b703 424c 2b2a
    0x0000010: b603 43b6 0344 2ab6 0345 b603 462a b603
    0x0000020: 47b6 0348 2ab6 0349 b603 4a2a b603 4bb6
    0x0000030: 034c 2ab6 034d b603 4e2a b603 4fb6 0350
    0x0000040: 2ab6 0351 b603 522a b603 53b6 0354 2ab6
    0x0000050: 0355 b603 5657 2ab6 0357 9900 0b2a b603
    0x0000060: 582b b803 592b b603 5ab0               
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@6)
    append_frame(@101,Object[#2149])
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.createPBHelper(FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.<clinit>(FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper.java:555)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.AsyncFSOutputHelper.createOutput(AsyncFSOutputHelper.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AsyncProtobufLogWriter.initOutput(AsyncProtobufLogWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AbstractProtobufLogWriter.init(AbstractProtobufLogWriter.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AsyncFSWALProvider.createAsyncWriter(AsyncFSWALProvider.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AsyncFSWAL.createWriterInstance(AsyncFSWAL.java:612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AsyncFSWAL.createWriterInstance(AsyncFSWAL.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AbstractFSWAL.rollWriter(AbstractFSWAL.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AbstractFSWAL.rollWriter(AbstractFSWAL.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AsyncFSWAL.<init>(AsyncFSWAL.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AsyncFSWALProvider.createWAL(AsyncFSWALProvider.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AsyncFSWALProvider.createWAL(AsyncFSWALProvider.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AbstractFSWALProvider.getWAL(AbstractFSWALProvider.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AbstractFSWALProvider.getWAL(AbstractFSWALProvider.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.WALFactory.getWAL(WALFactory.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getWAL(HRegionServer.java:2065)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.buildServerLoad(HRegionServer.java:1291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.tryRegionServerReport(HRegionServer.java:1172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:989)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-08-10 13:38:31,369 ERROR [regionserver/bynear170:16020] regionserver.HRegionServer: RegionServer abort: loaded coprocessors are: []
```

Comment: what is your java version. ?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_121"

Comment: Can you try changing the default wal provider to file system and check. you will have to add this entry in hbase-site.xml. 
 <property>
  <name>hbase.wal.provider</name>
  <value>filesystem</value>
 </property>

restart hbase and check.

Comment: This error is probably generated because of JAVA only. Check JAVA Path and check Java compatibility of the version with your Hadoop and HBase version

Comment: I change hbase version from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0,and it starts OK.